# How to make user to Like/Dislike post only for once in Django?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, python-3.x

Started learning Django a few days ago but now I'm stuck with this issue.
It's a blog website and i'm working with like/dislike function at the moment.
For now authenticated user can like the same post as many times as he wants.
I guess there's problem with my model. (Or maybe its conditions in my view)
I would be very grateful for the help and clarifications! :)

Here's my model (Post.py):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Пользователь", related_name='author')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Название")
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст публикации")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Дата создания")
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Дата обновления")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400,verbose_name = "Описание")
    reading_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Время для чтения в минутах")
    likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    users_reaction = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, verbose_name='Реакция юзеров', related_name='react')
```

My view (Post.py):

```
class UserReactionView(View):
    template_name='post.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post_id = self.request.GET.get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(id = post_id)
        like = self.request.GET.get('like')
        dislike = self.request.GET.get('dislike')
        post_user_reactions = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        if like and (request.user not in post_user_reactions.all()):
            post.likes += 1
            post.users_reaction.add(request.user)
            post.save()
        if dislike and (request.user not in post_user_reactions.all()):
            post.dislikes += 1
            post.users_reaction.add(request.user)
            post.save()
        data = {
            'likes': post.likes,
            'dislikes': post.dislikes
        }

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

And jquery block in the template

```
{% block jquery %}
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#like').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault()
          var post_id = {{ post.pk }}
          var like = 'like'

          data = {
              post_id: post_id,
              like: like
          }
          $.ajax ({
              type:"GET",
              url:"{% url 'blog:user_reaction'  post.pk%}",
              dataType: 'json',
              data: data,
              success: function(data){
                  $('#liked').html(data.likes)
                  $('#disliked').html(data.dislikes)

              }
          })
      })

  })

     $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#dislike').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault()
          var post_id = {{ post.pk }}
          var dislike = 'dislike'

          data = {
              post_id: post_id,
              dislike: dislike
          }
          $.ajax ({
              type:"GET",
              url:"{% url 'blog:user_reaction' post.pk %}",
              dataType: 'json',
              data: data,
              success: function(data){
                  $('#liked').html(data.likes)
                  $('#disliked').html(data.dislikes)

              }
          })
      })

  })
</script>

 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is wrong:

```
post_user_reactions = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

This query filters out all the posts that `request.user` has created.

Change it like this:

```
post_obj = Post.objects.get(id = post_id)
# Now get all the users that reacted to this post.
post_user_reactions = post_obj.users_reaction.all()

if like and (request.user not in post_user_reactions):
    ...
if dislike and (request.user not in post_user_reactions):
    ...
```

Comment: Yea, but when I click on the like button I get the following error: post_user_reactions = Post.users_reaction.all()
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: Do you have the post instance? `post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)`. This error usually happens when you have a queryset instead of an instance.

Comment: `def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post_id = self.request.GET.get('post_id')
        post = Post.objects.get(id = post_id) ` **<----------- here i have it** 
       `like = self.request.GET.get('like')
        dislike = self.request.GET.get('dislike')
        post_user_reactions = Post.users_reaction.all()
        if like and (request.user not in post_user_reactions):
            post.likes += 1
            post.users_reaction.add(request.user)
            post.save()`

Comment: You're querying the model not the instance. `Post` is not the same as `post`. Notice the lower cased "p". I recommend renaming the `post` to `post_obj`. Renamed in the answer too.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. You can accept the answer if it answered your question correctly.